# Filter data from queryset in Django wihtout returning the entire queryset

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-rest-framework

I'm trying get an attribute from a given object in Djano. I'm getting the value properly but I'm curious as if there is a better way to grab this data.

I'm getting the name attribute by using:

```
owner_name = Owner.objects.filter(id=id).values('name')
```

And it properly returns the `name` attribute I'm looking for, but it is in the form of:

```
<QuerySet [{'name': u'John Doe'}]>
```

How can I get it to just return "John Doe" instead of `<QuerySet [{'name': u'John Doe'}]>`?

Edit: I've found out that I can get the info I need by doing:
`owner_name[0].get('name')`

and it will return `John Doe`. Is there a better way to do this still just to get 1 attribute?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want a `values_list` query with the `flat=True` parameter. From the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#values-list):

> A common need is to get a specific field value of a certain model instance. To achieve that, use values_list() followed by a get() call:
>
> Entry.objects.values_list('headline', flat=True).get(pk=1)

Or in your case:

```
Owner.objects.values_list('name', flat=True).get(id=id)
```

Note that `get` will raise an exception if there is not exactly one matching result. If that's a possibility, say because you were filtering on something other than id or because there might be no matching object, you could catch the exceptions or you could work with the list of names returned and check its length.

Comment: Thank you. Exactly what I must have missed when reading the docs. I can handle the exception then.